# inactive Menu title does not show in FluidBottomNavigation Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using [this](https://github.com/10clouds/FluidBottomNavigation-android) library in one of my Android(Kotlin) project. I was just wondering if there's a way to have an attribute for keeping titles visible by default while navigating through tabs. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance for any answer!

Like that:

[image]

Comment: `bottomNavigationView.labelVisibilityMode=LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED`